# Authentication: forced to refresh page to be authorised

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, jwt, express-jwt

I'm using the code from [this blog](https://blog.hyphe.me/token-based-authentication-with-node/) to make an authentication module for my angular app.

I have a test page that includes a login form, a submit button and a "profile" button that will query a restricted route.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="AuthCtrl as auth">
    <input type="text" ng-model="auth.user.username">
    <input type="text" ng-model="auth.user.password">
    <button ng-click="auth.login(auth.user)">LOGIN</button>
    <button ng-click="auth.profile()">PROFILE</button>
</div>
```

The restricted route I'm querying after login is defined as:

```
const authenticate = expressJwt({
  secret: SECRET
});
app.get('/me', authenticate, function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(req.user);
});
```

The login works fine. I receive a token that I put in sessionStorage.
When I click on the profile button (request to /me) I get an unauthorized error.

If I refresh the page and click again on profile I do get the excpected behaviour. (/me returns user data with no error)

If I delete the token manually after that, I still have access to /me until I refresh the page.

This is my service:

```
function loginService($http) {
    this.login = function(user) {
        return $http.post('/auth', user).then(
            function(response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function(response) {
                return response;
            });
    };
    this.profile = function() {
        return $http.get('/me').then(
            function(response) {
                return response.data;
            },
            function(response) {
                return response;
            });
    };
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .service('loginService', loginService);
```

And this is my controller with the httpProvider:

```
function AuthCtrl($window, $http, loginService) {
    this.user = {username: "", password: ""};
    this.login = function(user) {
        loginService.login(user).then(function(data) {
            $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
        });
    };
    this.profile = function() {
        loginService.profile().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
}

function config($httpProvider, $windowProvider) {
    var window = $windowProvider.$get();
    if(window.sessionStorage.token) {
        var token =  window.sessionStorage.token;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config)
    .controller('AuthCtrl', AuthCtrl);
```

Could the problem come from storing the token in sessionStorage or from the http provider?

Eventually I will implement the [secure cookie method](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-authentication-angularjs) but I'd like to get this one solved before proceding further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out it was coming for the `$httpProvider` code.

```
function config($httpProvider, $windowProvider) {
    var window = $windowProvider.$get();
    if(window.sessionStorage.token) {
        var token =  window.sessionStorage.token;
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    }
};
```

The provider options wer set only once during app load.
Reloading the page would rerun the config code and enter the `if(window.sessionStorage.token)` condition as expected.

To make this config dynamic, I had to create an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) (factory) like so:

```
function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
};

function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                console.log("not authorised");
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
};

angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config)
    .controller('AuthCtrl', AuthCtrl)
    .factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);
```